# What is the right way to edit/delete items from ListView

Tags: android, listview

So, I have MainActivity with ArrayList< MyObject>, ListView for display it and EditActivity to get UI for editing items. Adapter for ListView extends ArrayAdapter< MyObject>. When user click on item I want to start EditActivity with object for editing. How could I put the object to EditActivity? I have:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

how could I get the object in EditActivity?
Of course, I could declare ArrayList< MyObject> as static and put index of the item with:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("index", iItemIdex);
    startActivity(i);
```

and then, in EditActivity, get it like:

```
    int iIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("index");
    MyObject o = MainActivity.MyArray.get(iIndex);
```

but I guess that is not best decision :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to declare your List static. Here is the code you should have to get it to work (one possibility) :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    MyObjectClass obj = (MyObjectClass) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("myKey", obj);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This way there is no useless static variables, and you are using the method the way it has been made for. One of the easiest and cleanest solution IMO.
**Be carefull**, to use this method, your have to redefine the `getItem(int)` method in your custom `ArrayAdapter`. You should do this :

```
@Override
public MyObjectClass getItem(int position) {
    return this.myList.get(position);
}
```

**EDIT :** Then if you want to be able to remove items, I think you should put the whole list containing your objects in the intent (don't declare it static). Then just call add()/remove() methods, and when you want to update UI to show the modifed list, just call notifyDataSetChanged() on your custom ArrayAdapter, for example when returning in MainActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    yourListAdater.notifyDataSetChanged();
    /* Assuming you have a reference pointing to your adapter in your MainActivity, if you don't just do: ((MyCustomAdapterClass) myListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); */
}
```

Comment: Ehm...          
    intent.put("myKey", obj);
    Error: The method put(String, MyObject) is undefined for the type Intent...

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer. Note that the object you want to put in the intent has to implement Serializable interface. If the object you want to put in is a List, the objects it contains have to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit a `ListView`, you just edit the `ArrayAdapter` by using its `add`, `insert`, `remove`, and `clear` functions on the Adapter.

After you've done that, you call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify that the contents of the `ArrayAdapter` have changed. Your `ListView` will be updated with the new values.

Comment: How to do this from another activity - that is the question